# Do Apple templates contain a bug since they cast to BOOL?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, boolean, null

According to [Mike Ash's blog post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-12-14-objective-c-pitfalls.html) casting to BOOL can fail 6% of the time since a pointer is larger than a BOOL. Because of this he recommends that if you are checking if an object exists you should check against nil

```
if (self != nil) {
```

instead of what Apple templates do which is

```
if (self) {
```

Do Apple's templates contain a bug or is there some other syntactical sugar I don't know about?

Comment: Daij-Djan: Sorry, I didn't mean to annoy, just the `1+` part made it a bit obscure.

Comment: Mike Ash's post doesn't actually talk about `if` and casts to `BOOL` together. They're in separate sections, discussing separate pitfalls: The one about `if`, which is the first one, is about chained comparisons such as `0 <= i < count`, and the section you're talking about is about situations such as `return` statements and assignments (where there is, in fact, a cast to the destination type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C is based on C, and in C the `if` statement does, maybe surprisingly, not operate on boolean values.

C has a hierarchy of types:

- The `char`, integer, and enumeration (`enum`) types are the *integer types*
- The `float`, `double` and `long double` are the *real floating types*
- There are three complex number types which together with the real floating types are termed simply the *floating point types*
- The integer types and floating point types combined form the *arithmetic types*
- The arithmetic types along with the pointer types form the *scalar types*

Phew!

Now to the `if` statement, it is of one of the forms:

```
if ( expression ) statement
if ( expression ) statement else statement
```

Where *expression* must be of *any scalar type*. The first (or only) *statement* is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0, the second (if present) *statement* is executed if the expression compares equal to 0.

So:

```
if (self) ...
```

and

```
if (self != nil) ...
```

are identical in *result*.

The first expression `self` is some pointer type, which is a *scalar type*, and is compared for being unequal to the zero of the pointer type (represented in code by `nil`). The second expression `self != nil` is an *equality-expression* and yields either `0` or `1` of type `int`, which is also a *scalar type*...

So technically the second form involves the intermediate production of an `int` value, but no compiler will actually produce one (unless you assign the result of the expression to a variable of course).

*Notes:*

1. Somewhat bizarrely `if ( sin( angle ) ) ...` is valid...
2. The `switch` statement operates on *integer types* and not *scalar types*

HTH

Comment: Another point, in addition to the definition of `if`, is the fact that that definition comes from C. `BOOL` does not exist in C; it is defined in one of the Objective-C headers, and is an extension by Objective-C. As such, it cannot be part of the definition of anything defined by C. (There is a native Boolean type in C99, but it's separate from both `BOOL` and the definition of `if`.)

Comment: @PeterHosey - well it *could* be something special C as it is just a typedef (for `signed char`) not a new type, so it's *rather unlikely* as opposed to *cannot* ;-)

Answer (score 12):

> since they cast to BOOL

No, they don't. There is no cast performed at all. There is, however, evaluation of an expression as a logic value. In the case of pointers (which `nil` and `self` are), a `NULL` pointer evaluates to false, anything else to true. This is not a bug, just a shorthand way and it's perfectly valid C.

Concerning why one might want to perform an explicit comparison against `NULL` or `nil`: in some cases, it may be more readable, especially if it's not obvious at first glance of what type and range the expression is. However, in Objective-C and Cocoa, it's such a common idiom in a constructor to do this, that any experienced programmer will grasp it without problem.

Comment: @0x7fffffff Thanks! :D Well, at least you can go ahead and fix my English when necessary (just happened :P )

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about your English. I live in America and apparently a lot of people in our age bracket here have decided that butchering the English language should be a trend. I'm only saying that to say that you speak better English than many of a native English speakers I know.

Comment: @0x7fffffff That's very nice to hear, actually :) Given that the same is true for French spelling and ortography in general, I should probably consider getting an MA in languages instead of an MSc in CS... ;-) And don't worry, in my country, Hungary, the same phenomenon is present, mostly among young people - I'm continuously trying not to fall into this "stupid teenager" category.

Comment: @SteveMoser Why should it be different?

Comment: Side note to those coming from Java and similar background. In languages like Java there is no way to evaluate expressions which are not Boolean. Java won't accept `if (my_integer)` nor `if (this)` only `if (0 != my_integer)` and `if (null != this)` are valid there. It is good to have it said clearly that in C (and Objective C) expression are evaluated under strict rules but without any casting.

Comment: @H2CO3 ah nm, I see now. For some reason I thought putting it in a conditional cast it to one of these bad BOOLs. Accepted because you gave the why though I would accept Inder's answer if I could accept both.

Answer (score 3):

No, this can't fail if the pointer isn't nil, it's safe and the only difference is the syntax, and I wouldn't recommend one or another way, since they're the same.
You aren't casting self to a BOOL, you' re just checking if self is different from zero.

Comment: This can fail, see Inder's answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's the same see my edit. I was Logging wrong debug mesage

Comment: Inders's answer does not prove that `if (self)` can fail, see my comment to that answer.

Comment: My answer is right, maybe you misunderstood.So I edited my answer and entered in pedantic mode.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited**
As per Martin's comment I was logging wrong debug messages.
It's the same

Here is a simple test

```
NSString *str = nil;
// suppose our string points to a string object whose starting address is 0x4500
//I'm assigning it manually so that I can test
str = 0x4500;
NSLog(@"%d",str);
if (str) {
    NSLog(@"It's non-nil");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"It's nil");
}

if (str == nil) {
    NSLog(@"It's nil");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"It's non-nil");
}
```

Output is :

```
It's non-nil
It's non-nil
```

Comment: Your first test is wrong: `if (str) { NSLog(@"It's nil"); } ...` makes no sense, it should be `if (str) { NSLog(@"It's non-nil"); } ...` !! And then you see that `if (str)` and `if (str != nil)` always have the same result.

Comment: @H2CO3 I was logging wrong output. Now edited my answer and it's as expected by your anser

Comment: @InderKumarRathore There was no sarcasm in my previous comment. Thanks for pointing out how exactly this can be broken.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the catch. Other wise I was searching for this problem since then. Now I got some relief that apple is doing right thing :). Hence the above blog seems to be wrong by this example

Comment: The blog states only the you should not cast a pointer to a BOOL. But `if (self)` does not cast `self` to a BOOL, as H2CO3 correctly said. So both the blog and Apple are right.

Comment: @MartinR Again you are right. In that blog he is preventing us to cast an object to `BOOL`.